# How do I add a button on google map?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I have placed the button in a fragment as I have seen on another post
about the same subject but It didn't work

Comment: Place the `Button` tag before your map's fragment. In Layouts like `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, widget declared first stays on top where as in Layouts like `ConstraintLayout`, `FrameLayout`, widget declared last stays on top.

Answer (score 1):

your XML code have problem , I think you putted Button under Map , please share Full of your XML code .
its better to use Constraint Layout .